# How to make this HTML form scalable?

Tags: html, css

I have a login page. It doesn't have much text, and it is quite readable in big screens, such as a laptop or a tablet. However, in a mobile one has to zoom it until he sees what is written there. I want to make it scalable, but it looks like I don't know how to do it. Here is the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <style>
  .big {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="form1" action="enter.php" method="post">
    <table class="big">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
         <img src="http://www.lipsum.com/images/banners/grey_234x60.gif">
        </td>
       </tr>
        <td align="right">Name:</td>
        <td align="left"><input id="Username" name="Username" size="25" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Pass:</td>
        <td align="left"><input id="Password" name="Password" size="25" type="password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Sumbit"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make adaptive and responsive design . You can use these libraries to help you make a responsive grid, for example:

http://getskeleton.com/

They use "media queries " for responsive design, you leave a link :

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you, I will use this!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below line between your `<head>...</head>` tag

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use this!

Answer (score 1):

Only to give you an idea about the elements envolved...
Expand the snipet in fuul screen than resize browser page.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Login</title>
      <style>
      .big {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   body {
   font-size:1.6em;
        }

 input{
         width: 90%;
         font-size: 1.4em;
          }
input[type="submit"] {
          width: 50%;
                      }
}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form name="form1" action="enter.php" method="post">
        <table class="big">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
             <img src="http://www.lipsum.com/images/banners/grey_234x60.gif">
            </td>
           </tr>
            <td align="right">Name:</td>
            <td align="left"><input id="Username" name="Username" size="25" type="text"></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Pass:</td>
            <td align="left"><input id="Password" name="Password" size="25" type="password"></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="text-align:left"><input type="submit" value="Sumbit"></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use your approach!